# Directions Issue in Map View

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to provide directions to certain areas I have marked with map pins on my map view. On those pins I have displayed the name of the location and where it is located. I would like for them to be able to click the "i" that is usually on some Apple "pop ups" and it direct them to the Maps app and give them directions based on the coordinates I programmed in to place the map pin where it is. I will post two pictures first of what I have and what I would like to accomplish.

**What I have right now**

[image]

**What I want to add to my pin (just the "i")**

[image]

Now I will post my code of how I accomplished my first screenshot.

**ViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
MKMapView *mapView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

-(IBAction)SetMap:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)GetLocation:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)Directions:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MapPin.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Moss Preserve coordinates
MKCoordinateRegion MossPreserveRegion = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
MossPreserveRegion.center.latitude = 33.3816566;
MossPreserveRegion.center.longitude = -86.8415451;
MossPreserveRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 55.0;
MossPreserveRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 55.0;
[mapView setRegion:MossPreserveRegion animated:YES];

//Moss Preserve annotation and map pin
MapPin *MossPreserveAnnotation = [[MapPin alloc] init];
MossPreserveAnnotation.title = @"Moss Rock Preserve Boulder Fields";
MossPreserveAnnotation.subtitle = @"Hoover, AL";
MossPreserveAnnotation.coordinate = MossPreserveRegion.center;
[mapView addAnnotation:MossPreserveAnnotation];

//Horse Pens 40 coordinates
MKCoordinateRegion HorsePenRegion = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
HorsePenRegion.center.latitude = 33.9207535;
HorsePenRegion.center.longitude = -86.3089447;
HorsePenRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 55.0;
HorsePenRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 55.0;
[mapView setRegion:HorsePenRegion animated:YES];

//Horse Pens 40 annotation and map pin
MapPin *HorsePenAnnotation = [[MapPin alloc] init];
HorsePenAnnotation.title = @"Horse Pens 40";
HorsePenAnnotation.subtitle = @"Steele, AL ";
HorsePenAnnotation.coordinate = HorsePenRegion.center;
[mapView addAnnotation:HorsePenAnnotation];

// Create an MKMapItem to pass to the Maps app
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]  initWithCoordinate:MossPreserveAnnotation.coordinate
                                               addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mossPreserveMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mossPreserveMapItem setName:MossPreserveAnnotation.title];

NSDictionary *launchOptions = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};
// Get the "Current User Location" MKMapItem
placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:HorsePenRegion.coordinate
                                  addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *horsePenMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
horsePenmapItem.name = HorsePenRegion.title;

// Pass the current location and destination map items to the Maps app
// Set the direction mode in the launchOptions dictionary
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[mossPreserveMapItem, horsePenmapItem]
               launchOptions:launchOptions];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)SetMap:(id)sender;
{
switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex)
{
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        break;
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
        break;
    case 2:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}

-(IBAction)GetLocation:(id)sender;
{
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}

-(IBAction)Directions:(id)sender;
{
NSString *urlString = @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=33.3816566,-86.8415451";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
}

@end
```

**MapPin.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapPin : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

NSString *title;
NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

**MapPin.m:**

```
#import "MapPin.h"

@implementation MapPin

@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;

@end
```

I see this all of the time in apps that I use. i just don't even really know what it is called, so I could even search for it. I am not looking for someone to hold my hand and tell me the answer, just some proper guidance and constructive criticism.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "MapPin.h"
@import MapKit;

@interface MapViewController ()<MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _mapView.delegate = self;

    //Moss Preserve coordinates
    MKCoordinateRegion MossPreserveRegion = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
    MossPreserveRegion.center.latitude = 33.3816566;
    MossPreserveRegion.center.longitude = -86.8415451;
    MossPreserveRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 55.0;
    MossPreserveRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 55.0;
    [_mapView setRegion:MossPreserveRegion animated:YES];

    //Moss Preserve annotation and map pin
    MapPin *MossPreserveAnnotation = [[MapPin alloc] init];
    MossPreserveAnnotation.title = @"Moss Rock Preserve Boulder Fields";
    MossPreserveAnnotation.subtitle = @"Hoover, AL";
    MossPreserveAnnotation.coordinate = MossPreserveRegion.center;
    [_mapView addAnnotation:MossPreserveAnnotation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

        // Create an MKMapItem to pass to the Maps app
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]  initWithCoordinate:view.annotation.coordinate
                                                addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mossPreserveMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mossPreserveMapItem setName:view.annotation.title];

NSDictionary *launchOptions = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};

// Get the "Current User Location" MKMapItem
MKMapItem *currentLocationItem = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[mossPreserveMapItem, currentLocationItem]
               launchOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                       reuseIdentifier:@"MKPinAnnotationView"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailButton;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: What class does that take place of in my program?

Comment: it should be your ViewController

Comment: let me copy and see, give me 5 minutes

Comment: Is this giving me directions from moss preserve to horse pens? What I was looking for was to get directions to one of those from my current location. So I have two pins, the first is moss preserve, when I press that I want directions from my current location to moss preserve. On the second pin, horse pens 40, when I press that pin I would like directions from my current location to horse pens 40... Is that possible?

Comment: I am really sorry I am being a nuisance.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for all of your help so far. I am staring to finally get my head wrapped around this

Comment: edited the solution with current location. Look at calloutAccessoryControlTapped:

Comment: Ok, last thing I promise. It is all working perfectly. The only thing is that it is giving me directions in reverse. It is giving me directions from my map pin to my current location. It needs to be from my current location to the map pin...

Comment: just change order of arguments when passing into [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:] method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53931/discussion-between-javageek-and-longnv)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 2 map items for your locations and pass as arguments to MKMapItem's openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:

```
// Create an MKMapItem to pass to the Maps app
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:MossPreserveAnnotation.coordinate 
                                        addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItem1 = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mapItem setName:MossPreserveAnnotation.title];

NSDictionary *launchOptions = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};
// Get the "Current User Location" MKMapItem
placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:HorsePenAnnotation.coordinate 
                                        addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItem2 = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
mapItem2.name = HorsePenAnnotation.title;

// Pass the current location and destination map items to the Maps app
// Set the direction mode in the launchOptions dictionary
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[mapItem1, mapItem2] 
                launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Comment: How do you create map items? And our map items the "i" that I was referring to?

Comment: I posted my updated code, it doesn't like my ".coordinate" and ".title". It says "No member named 'coordinate' in 'MKCoordinateRegion" and "No member named 'title' in 'MKCoordinateRegion".

Comment: You cannot use MKCoordinateRegion because it has not specific coordinate. Instead use your map pins.

Comment: I am confused as what you are talking about, can you show an example of what you are saying? Sorry...

Comment: My mistake. I edite the sample code, it should use HorsePenAnnotation instead of HorsePenRegion.

Comment: Ok, i am sorry I keep asking questions, but the code you gave me did execute, but not what I was trying to accomplish. I want to add that "i" as I am calling it that I showed in my 2 pictures to the side of my first one for each pin on my map. So whenI press my mapView button on my app it opens up that view with the map and map pins showing. Then I can press each individual map pin and it show the title, location that I have listed in my picture along with the "i" that you can press to send you to the maps app..... Make sense?

Comment: The code that you gave me and that I placed in my method did when I hit my button it sent me straight to my maps app giving me directions to HorsePens.